# How to add UIBarButtonItem in UIToolBar in code

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have standart UIBarButtonItem

```
UIBarButtonItem *share = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(share:)];
```

How to add her to UIToolBar? I've tried

```
    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:share];
```

But it doesn't work. Need your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you be more specific than "it doesn't work"?

If you're trying to add an item to a toolbar that already has items, you'll need to modify the array of items:

```
NSMutableArray *newItems = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
[newItems addObject:share];
self.toolbarItems = newItems;
```

Comment: Sorry. It means that toolBar appears without any button. Now try to make your way

Comment: Find solution [self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:share]];

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you have make a toolbar either an IBOutlet or added toolbar programatically

```
IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolBar;

UIBarButtonItem *infoButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"info" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered  target:self action:@selector(infoButtonClicked)];

toolBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButtonItem, nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the toolbar isn't hidden; you could try adding the following to your view controller's `viewWillAppear:animated:` method:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

`[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:share] animated:YES];`